# Accordion-Collapse-react-native with scrollview

Tags: react-native, scrollview, accordion, collapsable, react-native-scrollview

I'm trying to add an accordion type view in my project and I'm using this library from github [Accordion-Collapse-react-native](https://github.com/marouanekadiri/Accordion-Collapse-react-native)

I was able to successfully integrate the library and it works but the problem is when I put it inside the scrollview it doesn't expand. If I don't put it inside the scrollview it works fine but it doesn't scroll. Not sure what I'm missing. Has anyone used this library? Can anyone help? Below is a sample of my code so far.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
          {/* Question Container */}
          <ScrollView
            ref={ref => (this.scrollView = ref)}
            style={styles.scrollContainer
            }
            scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
            onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
          >
            {this.renderHeaders()}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>


renderHeaders() {
    let headerList = [];

    var questionList = [];
    questionList = this.props.dataSource[this.props.currentHeading].questions;

    for (let i = 0; i < questionList.length; i++) {
      headerList.push(
        <Collapse>
          <CollapseHeader style={styles.headerStyle}>
            <Text>{questionList[i].question}</Text>
          </CollapseHeader>
          <CollapseBody>
            <Text>{questionList[i].questionDetail}</Text>
          </CollapseBody>
        </Collapse>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View>{headerList}</View> 
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at this
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/issues/106#issuecomment-317348819

It's a different package but the solution may work for you

Comment: Add **flexGrow:1** into scrollview style

Comment: @AlexandreLage, it doesn't work for me. In my case I'm able to scroll, it just the view that doesn't expand.

Comment: Try using this package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible

Comment: I tried to investigate your issue, this example shows how to [Snack example](https://snack.expo.io/Bka!Vx_1I)